# Multiprocessing Processes Not Joining In Python 3.7 but do in 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have some code that uses the multiprocessing module in Python (see below).

```
import multiprocessing

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1, args=(id,rootdir))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2, args=(id,rootdir))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func3, args=(id,rootdir))

jobs = [p1,p2,p3]

for job in jobs:
    job.start()

#won't join in python 3.7 but will in 3.5
for job in jobs:
    job.join()

print ('Finished tasks')
```

This code executes perfectly fine on Python 3.5. However on Python 3.7, the processes start but do not join. Instead what happens is Python tries to kill the main program. If I don't let it kill itself, it just hangs indefinitely. If I cancel it, the program terminates itself.

What is different in Python 3.7 that doesn't let me execute the same code?

Comment: cannot reproduce in python 3.7 with the functions `def func1(): time.sleep(1); print('done f1')
def func2(): time.sleep(2); print('done f2')
def func3(): time.sleep(3); print('done f3')`. it works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpreter I was using (IDLE) to run this script was not compatible with the multiprocessing module when running 'main' in 3.7. It does specify this in the docs. Since switching to just the command line version on Linux, my script is fine.